# How do I print out a specific node to my page?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'd just like to print out the body of a specific node (no title or other fields).  Am I doing this right?

```
echo node_load(127)->body['und'][0]['value']
```

I can't seem to find the answer in any of the Drupal docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking with the Devel module to the structure of a loaded node, I notice that "body" contains the following values:

[image: screenshot]

The first array index is the language ID for the language set for the node; it could be also [LANGUAGE_NONE](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7) (the string "und") for nodes for which the language is set to "neutral." That array index contains an array with the following indexes:

- "value": the content of the "body" field
- "summary": what set as summary (or teaser) for the node
- "format": the input format associated with the "body" field

In the node I used as example, if you try accessing `$node->body['und'][0]['value']`, you would access an undefined value. You should use `$node->language` to know the language set for the node; you code should be similar to the following one:

```
$node = node_load(127);
$body = $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'];
```

As for printing the body content, the "body" field contains the text before the input filter is applied; you should use code similar to the following one, to print the "body" field:

```
$node = node_load(127);
$language = $node->language;
print check_markup($node->body[$language][0]['value'], $node->body[$language][0]['format'], $language);
```

Comment: Should the second parameter to check_markup be $node->body[$language][0]['format']

Comment: You are right: The second parameter is the input format being applied.

Answer (score 4):

```
$node = node_load(127);
print $node->body;
```

Please, note, this outputs just the content of the Body textarea as input in the node form.

To output the fully themed node without title and links would require a separate template file, its introduction via a preprocess function, and a call to

```
print theme('node', $node);
```

Comment: OK, but `$node->body` is an array yeah?  Can you just print it out like that?

Comment: Nope, it's text/HTML/PHP (depending on the input filter). It's just the content of the Body field in the node form.

Comment: In Drupal 7, I'm pretty sure it is an array because print_r on $node->body shows an array structure like what I've used in the original question.  I think I tried what you suggested, but it only printed 'Array' to the screen.

Comment: Sorry, that was for d6. Retagged your question.